# Crear un filtro de precio

Tags: php

Ya he creado un buscador con PHP en el que seleccionas una letra o palabra y te busca en la base de datos. Quería saber como poder filtrar los datos que se han extraído de mi base de datos por precio, fecha etc...

El código que uso para mi buscador PHP:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "restaurantes");
$output = '';
$record_per_page = 5;  
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
  $page = $_POST['query'];
  $start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page; 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurantes_resultado WHERE nombre   
  LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' 
  OR precio LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' 
  OR fecha LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' 
 LIMIT 0 , 5 ";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $output .= '
   <div class="resultado margenes">
   <div class="imagen col">
   <a href="#" tittle="Imagen1" class="thumbnail"><img src="'.$row["fotos"].'"/></a>
   </div>
  <div class="contenido-medio col">
  <div id="no-margin">

  <h3 class="no-margin">'.$row["nombre"].'</h3> 

  <p> zona:'.$row["precio"].' </p>
  </div>

</div>
    <div class ="barra-vertical col">
    <p> '.$row["fecha"].' </p>
    </div>

    </div>
';} 
 echo $output;  
}else{
echo 'Data Not Found';
 }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es mejor pegar el codigo relevante en la pregunta. Mira los links que te pase.

Comment: vale lo tendré en cuenta..

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo, sólo tienes que agregar "`ORDER BY nombre_columna`" en la sentencia de MySQL para que los resultados se ordenen según la columna indicada.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM `usuarios` ORDER BY `nombre`
```

Lo que haria esta petición SQL es listar los usuarios, ordenados de manera alfabética según el nombre.

Comment: pero lo que quiero es poner un filtro con una barra para que sea el usuario el que indique que es lo que quiere ordenar, es decir un intervalo de precio entre X y X+1

Answer (score 0):

> pero lo que quiero es poner un filtro con una barra para que sea el usuario el que indique que es lo que quiere ordenar, es decir un intervalo de precio entre X y X+1

Entonces, tendrías que generar 2 variables (mínimo y máximo, en el caso del precio), y luego con PHP, al listar los datos con MySQL, verificar si el valor del precio es MAYOR, MENOR o IGUAL a los valores dados.

Ejemplo:

```
$p = (object) $_POST;
$precio = array( $p->pcio_min, $p->pcio_max );

// Código SQL
// Fin Código SQL

// Filtro
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    if ( ($data["precio"] > $precio[0] && $data["precio"] < $precio[1]) 
    || $data["precio"] == $precio[0] || $data["precio"] == $precio[1] ) {

        echo $data["precio"];

    }

}
```

Es sólo un ejemplo, podés modificarlo según tu necesidad.

Comment: es decir, poner el código que he pegado antes entre los comentarios que pones entre // Código SQL y Fin del Código SQL o crear un nuevo archivo SQL?

Comment: Claro, en esa parte ponés la petición SQL que quieras hacer.